# Upgrading from firebase version 8 to version 9 compat - Service firestore is not available

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my React app after upgrading firebase from version 8 to 9 (compat), I am getting this error:

```
provider.ts:130 Uncaught Error: Service firestore is not available
    at Provider.getImmediate (provider.ts:130:1)
    at La (index.esm2017.js:17277:1)
    at ./src/firebase.js (firebase.js:60:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./src/views-auth/LoginPage.js (LandingPage.js:208:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./src/layouts/Auth.js (Admin.js:276:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at ./src/index.js (firebase.js:186:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at 1 (StudentsPage.js:148:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:109
```

Below is the firebase imports and firebase app initialization.

**Imports:**

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/analytics";
import "firebase/compat/functions";
import "firebase/compat/storage";
```

**Firebase app initialize:**

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};
```

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const functions = firebase.functions();
const analytics = firebase.analytics();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "material-dashboard-pro-react",
  "version": "1.9.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity": "^3.154.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-polly": "^3.154.0",
    "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity": "^3.154.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.x",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.31",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments": "^0.0.6",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.14.2",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "compressorjs": "^1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.19.0",
    "detect-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "firebase": "9.12.1",
    "google-classroom-share": "^0.5.6",
    "google-translate": "^3.0.0",
    "history": "4.10.1",
    "http2": "^3.3.7",
    "instantsearch.css": "^7.4.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "5.1.9",
    "react-chartist": "0.14.3",
    "react-code-input": "^3.10.0",
    "react-confetti": "^6.0.1",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-gapi": "^1.0.2",
    "react-google-button": "^0.7.2",
    "react-google-charts": "^4.0.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-iframe": "^1.8.0",
    "react-instantsearch-hooks-web": "^6.33.0",
    "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
    "react-papaparse": "^3.16.1",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^3.10.0",
    "react-rewards": "^1.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-speech-recognition": "^3.7.0",
    "react-tagsinput": "3.19.0",
    "react-use-intercom": "^1.5.0",
    "react-voice-recorder": "^2.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.15.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "unsplash-js": "^7.0.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "npm run build",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/material-dashboard-pro-react.css",
    "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/material-dashboard-pro-react.min.css --output-style compressed",
    "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/material-dashboard-pro-react.css --source-map true",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.6",
    "@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.33",
    "ajv": "6.12.2",
    "typescript": "3.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.3",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.8",
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": []
  }
}
```

The firebase version is upgraded from 8.2.1 to 9.12.1.
I looked for similar issues but the solutions didn't work.
I tried changing the import URLs and reinstalling the v9 of firebase.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: What's the Firebase version installed on your package.json? Could you include your package.json in the question.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB I've added the package.json in the question.

Comment: Have you already tried removing/deleting the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`? If not, please do it then run: `npm i` and try to run it again. Your snippet works fine on my end.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB Yes, I tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json but it didn't work.
I deleted the firebase using yarn remove firebase and installed it again. Guess what? it worked.

Comment: Ohhh. Thats why.. I'm not aware that you're using different package manager. But yeah. What happened basically is you've been stucked with the old Firebase version and not using the updated one.

Comment: @SajjadHussain ,  I've posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki to help other community wiki that will encounter this issue.

`Service firestore is not available` error will occur on lower versions of Firebase as it doesn't have the updated **compat libraries**. Package managers sometimes tend to have some issues updating the libraries which makes the library stuck at the old version. By deleting or removing the existing installed library and reinstalling the latest version should be the solution. In this case, **Yarn** is used and it will be solved by doing this commands:

Firebase library removal:

```
yarn remove firebase
```

Firebase reinstallation:

```
yarn add firebase
```